# What do you call the people getting married in a wedding?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the people getting married at a wedding, i.e., the bride(s) and groom(s)? I was going to call them the "celebrants" but then I found out that "celebrant" is used for the preacher or whoever officiates at the ceremony. I want a word for the people who are taking the vows.

P.S. Is there a Latin-based word analogous to "officiant" or "celebrant"? The officiant read the wedding vows to the ________s?

What about "the principals"? Would that work?

Comment: The betrothed..

Comment: The wedding party would include bride and groom, bridesmaids and groomsmen, ushers, and anyone else participating in the ceremony.

Comment: The doomed, in some cases.  But for some reason they are often referred to as "the happy couple".

Comment: or "future newlyweds" ?

Comment: I tried to look up "connubiant" but that doesn't seem to be a word.

Comment: **affianced** or **intended** as a noun

Comment: @Graffito Or "future divorcees"? :)

Comment: The roles played by a bride vs. a groom in a wedding are so different that they deserve separate terms, i.e. I would almost always prefer "bride and groom" rather than any singular term. "betrothed" - maybe, but would need context to indicate it's referring to both people (since it would normally be referring to the other person from the perspective of the bride or groom)

Comment: "the people getting married at a wedding, i.e., the bride(s) and groom(s)" are indeed, actually, the bride and groom (or brides and grooms, if a multiple wedding ceremony).

Answer (score 3):

***Betrothed*** seems right:

> (adj.) "engaged to be married,"
>
> (n.) "the person to whom one is engaged;" e.g., "The preacher read the vows to the *betrothed*."
>
> Source: [*Collins English Dictionary*, via Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/betrothed)

Comment: This is a very reasonable answer, and it is at least a little bit better than the answer that civitas posted two years ago making the same suggestion. But what would make it upvote-worthy (in my opinion) would be the inclusion not merely of an example of the word's use in a sentence (which you've provided) but also a definition of the word itself, from a reputable dictionary, with a link (if possible) to the relevant dictionary page online. Please consider adding such a definition to your answer.

Comment: Very nice, Taylor—thanks for making the extra effort. +1

Comment: My pleasure.  Thanks for adjusting the formatting!

Answer (score 0):

the affianced, the betrothed, the engaged

Comment: These are better than "bridal couple," which doesn't sound gender neutral to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

"The bridal couple" is what I would use.

Comment: This has become more relevant since the introduction of "Civil ceremonies", which in the UK can be between two people of either gender.  The terminology seems to simply be "the couple".

Comment: *The happy couple* is a common phrase: they may not stay happy, but on their wedding day they definitely are (by convention).